# How about dedicating some corner of SE to opinions/recommendations / make a spinoff that will handle forums?

Tags: feature-request

Questions for opinions or recommendations are off-topic here, and I can understand why: whatever answer would be given it will hardly be timeless, and with vague problems, answers will necessarily will be biased in one way or another, presenting a limited opportunity for helping others as the time goes by.

The alternative is forum based approach, where the questions (threads) *are* expected to die off on their own. But on the other hand threads are plagued by off-topic or too lengthy conversations.

Why not devise a corner of SE dedicated to questions that would require a speculative answer and take advantage of this superb Q&A platform?

Main advantages over traditional forum software are:

- UI that focuses on a paradigm "one question, many independent answers" in contrast to forum, that looks more like an email conversation with "one question, nobody knows where are the answers among those 500 replies"
- Exquisite platform for moderators, that ensures that the level of moderator work is many levels beyond of what can be seen on forums
- A good and interesting system of points and badges that stimulates people to give answers on topic and rate them.

---

I'd badly need some good place, where I can get updates about the BTRFS vs ZFS, or bcache vs flashcache technologies.

The point system could be easily made adjusted so it will fade in time, so that a new and more up-date answer would get some bonus over very good, but old and outdated one.

Comment: You might be interested in [ubuntu discourse](http://discourse.ubuntu.com).